# matplotlib Annotation: how to get bbox only for text

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations

I would like to *test annotation objects* in my graph *for overlapping* and, if one object covers another, move them accordingly.

However `box = ann.get_window_extent(renderer)` gets the box for whole Annotation object and it does not help.

Is it possible to get the `bbox` for a Text object inside the Annotation?

The annotations in my example were created with

```
ax.annotate(str(point), (0, 0),
            (point[0], point[1]),
            xycoords=xycoords, textcoords=textcoords,
            bbox=bbox_props, size=96, ha=ha, va=va,
            arrowprops=arrowprops))
```

where `point` was of the form `(1, 1)`, `bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="round,pad=0.15", fc="blue", alpha=0.4)` and `arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", lw=0.8)`.

I'm thinking about placing empty annotations and Text objects separately, so the testing would be possible -- but, perhaps, it is not necessary?

(The image shows that points scattered for a corner of each bbox indicate, that the boxes are way too big, for my needs of overlapping test."+" for (0, 0), "x" for (1, 0) and triangles for (1, 1).
Boxes were accessed with `box = ann.get_window_extent(rr).transformed(ax.transData.inverted())` -- the transformation was necessary, corners with `box.corners()`. The labels in example image are just fine, but after it was enlarged to full screen.)
[image: plot with example annotations with bboxes indicated]

Comment: Did you try `ann.get_bbox_patch()`?

Comment: @Guimoute Yes, I tried. `ann.get_bbox_patch()` returns `None` since
    *get_bbox_patch() method of matplotlib.text.Annotation instance
    Return the bbox Patch, or None if the `.patches.FancyBboxPatch`
    is not made.*
(doc).
I don't know how to 'made' such a `FancyBboxPatch`.

Comment: If you don't want to roll your own solution, you may want to use [adjustText](https://github.com/Phlya/adjustText).